# execute ssis package for another server, didn't see any files

Tags: file, ssis, permissions, server, unc

I have SSIS package and on VISUAL STUDIO working good, for another server pre production also, but when i use production server and try loading xls files nothing do, didn't see any files. I hv the same permission both server sql so i Somebody can help me? I will be maximum enjoye if somebody will react!

Comment: I forgot write that i use UNC path

Comment: Seems like it could be a million different things.  Your question is way too vague.  you provide too few details to diagnose it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the suggestions!
My package imports xls files into a database on sql server
In the package I have a foreich loop cointainer and in the directory I use the variable " input folder path" .In the expression on my menager connection i have variable "Full Path" (with file name)
On preproduction server, the package is great and loads xls files. On production  server no. And i have comunicat :"For each file enumerator, no files were found that matched the file pattern or the specified directory was empty." 
I set delay validation (connection manager, task) is true, When i deploy on server my project again, the message "another user uses files" Nobody use this folder. only me.
I Use the mapped path // ​​fileserv / clientspath.filename.
I do not know what else i can write about this will be help self ..